stm32f103 arduino ide how to read pins A0..A7 as single byte?
I'm using STM32F103 in Arduino IDE. I have parallel 8bit data on pins A0..A7, to read them into a byte I use this:
int b = digitalReadFast(PA_0) + 
    digitalReadFast(PA_1) * 2 + 
    digitalReadFast(PA_2) * 4 + 
    digitalReadFast(PA_3) * 8 + 
    digitalReadFast(PA_4) * 16 + 
    digitalReadFast(PA_5) * 32 + 
    digitalReadFast(PA_6) * 64 + 
    digitalReadFast(PA_7) * 128;

This works but it's too slow at around 200kHz. Using << has same speed. Is there a way to make it faster by reading entire port A at once? There is PINA in AVR based arduinos but PINA doesn't work in STM32 in arduino IDE.

I'm not in a position to test this, but it looks like int b = 0xFF & *portInputRegister(digitalPinToPort(PA_0)); might work.

Yes it worked but I had to use PA_7 not PA_0. Read speed increased from 200kHz to 3MHz.

You can simply read direct from the Input Data Register of Port A with int b = GPIOA->IDR & 0xFF. This is the equivalent to the AVR PINA that you are referring to...

Even faster at 3.8MHz
